# webview images are not loading in lollipop versions when i give target sdk version has 21 in manifest file

Tags: android-image

I am developing an android Web view App. Its working fine when I set target S D K version is below 21,but if I set version as 21 Web view image tags (images) are not loading in lollipop devices.

I searched for the answer but I didn't find any where.Please help me to fix this problem. its working fine for all other previous versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow mixed content since default behaviour changed in API21 as described here:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setMixedContentMode(int)

```
webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
```